# unable to access Manjaro (kernel file not found)

Tags: grub, manjaro

I have Prime OS and Windows 10 alongside Linux Manjaro. I was using Prime OS nearly 2 hours. Then, I turned off my laptop for 30-60 minutes. Then, I turned my laptop on and I was using Windows 10 for 1 hours. After working on Windows 10, I had thought to work in Linux Manjaro. So, I turned my laptop off. Unfortunately, It was taking too much time to turn off my laptop that's why I had turned my laptop off by power button. Again, Windows 10 was automatically opening (without showing grub). So, I had again turned my laptop off by power button again. **When I turned my laptop on and clicked on Linux Manjaro, I saw the following screen.**

```
error: file `/boot/vmlinuz-5.10-x86_64' not found.
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue..._
```

I think that I can't access Manjaro's file from Windows or, Prime OS (I am not sure). How can I turn on Manjaro?

Here's my grub info
[image: grub info]

I have found following solutions

1. https://forum.manjaro.org/t/boot-file-not-found/60059
2. https://forum.manjaro.org/t/file-boot-vmlinuz-5-4-x86-64-not-found/18488
3. https://forum.manjaro.org/t/manjaro-unable-to-boot-error-file-boot-vmlinuz-5-7-x86-64-not-found/18445/3

Currently, I don't have bootable USB. So, how can I deal with it from grub? I can move to grub command-line also.

I had said what I did before starting Manjaro. After searching little bit, I remember that I had broke updating system. I had run following command

```
sudo pacman -Syyu
```

Then, I had pressed on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Since then, I am facing the problem.

---

Currently what i am thinking that is searching for vmlinuz somehow in Manjaro from grub command line.

[image: Image alt text]

I had tried
with `search`,`locate`,`find`. None of them were working. But, search option was used for something else.

Comment: That picture is very big and, i can't copy those texts. Thats why i gave picture

Comment: Can you add a screen photograph with less blur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are unfortunately not the only one to run into this problem. Many people interrupt the update process because they think their machine is hanging, and then they press the reset button.** For other people, there may be other reasons why the update process gets interrupted, but an interrupted update will indeed leave you without a bootable kernel, because the kernel images are only properly installed during the last phase of the update process.

I was trying to solve the problem from grub command line. But, I couldn't solve it from grub. That's why I had to take a bootable USB. I had installed Manjaro in that USB. You can use Arch-Linux also. I had opened terminal in Manjaro. Then, I executed following command.

```
sudo su -             #to be a root user
manjaro-chroot -a     #to find my Manjaro system. And, be a root user in that system
```

> This will autodetect your Manjaro installation. If you have multiple operating systems installed, then you may need to enter a number from a list.

```
pacman-mirrors -f 5 && pacman -Syyu        #update Manjaro system
exit                                       #to exit Manjaro system
exit                                       #to exit from root user
reboot now                                 #to reboot your PC. You can run the command without exiting from root user
```

Actually, you faced the issue for interrupting while updating system. That's why you lost your kernel. When you will update the Manjaro system than, it will work fine again.